# Use a checkmark as an column alias in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a requirement to do something I believe should be simple enough, but am not finding the right answer to. How do I use a checkmark as a column alias in SQL Server 2008 R2?

I've tried using `Char(251)` by setting it to a value and trying to assign the value as the column alias, but no joy on that one.

I've tried using `Char(251)` (and I know that's more of a square root mark, but not sure of the checkmark ascii value if there is one. I believe that is a unicode value?) directly but again no joy. This should be simple, but I'm simply not finding it.

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider doing this type of customization in your application end rather which is much more flexible than doing in DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use expressions as identifiers in SQL Server (or any other SQL database for that matter). You can, however, use Unicode characters in identifiers, so simply copy and paste the desired character:

```
select 'yes' as "☑︎";
```

or even

```
select 'blah' as "";
```

Having said that, you should not be doing all that -- presentation is not the task for a database engine; it should be implemented in the client application.

Comment: Yes you can use expression as Identifiers but you would need to use dynamic sql for it.

Comment: I totally agree with you on the presentation, but I am under a severe time crunch and they keep changing the requirements at the last moment.  This way seemed faster to me for this change.  Thanks.